# Conditional colour based formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to make an excel sheet with the different neuronal cell types.

If one of the cells in Column 1 or multiple cells are green, the selective cells in different columns should turn green as well.

Is it even possible to fill cell colour based on colour of the other cells?

Comment: Can you share a mock screenshot?

Comment: Are the cell colors in the first column set due to conditional formatting or manually?